# Nautilus crashes when I open but runs with sudo

Tags: permissions, nautilus, sudo, filemanager

I just upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and one of the issues I'm facing is that I can't view any folders and files because Nautilus crashes as soon as I try to open it:

```
$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2019.02.14
Bus error (core dumped)
```

However, it works normally if I run `sudo nautilus`.

This makes me think there may be due to some sort of **permission error**.

How can I check which (if any) file Nautilus is trying to read which is causing it to crash?

**Things I have tried**

- reinstall nautilus
- make sure config files are owned by me: `$ sudo chown -R felipe:felipe ~/.config/*`
- make sure dropbox config files under `~/.dropbox/` and under `~/.dropbox-dist` are owned by me
- list all files under my home and chown all configs and cache related files. (I couldn't chown `/.gvfs` and `~/.cache/doc`, I get `Function not implemented` error message)
- purge package `nautilus-dropbox` (it is not installed at all)
- purge `dropbox`. Same error message but without the previous dropbox-related debug text:

  ```
  $ nautilus
  Bus error (core dumped)
  ```
- ran `strace nautilus` for debugging. Last lines of log are [here](https://pastebin.com/jBDURhpm)

---

**PS** the log message for when the nautilus app crashes at startup is different from the one I get when running `nautilus`  on the cmd line. Here is the log for the startup crash: https://pastebin.com/mVx0E7SE

Comment: This is caused by running nautilus with sudo. That's a bad practice. You have nautilus config files owned by root.

Comment: I only ran it with sudo when it started crashing when running normally without sudo.

Comment: What about `~/.dropbox` files?

Comment: Yep those too. Updated the text.

Comment: Does the issue also happen in another user account?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest removing `nautilus-dropbox` by

```
sudo apt purge nautilus-dropbox
```

If you need a Dropbox service, you'd better install it from the Dropbox site.

https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2019.02.14_amd64.deb

If nothing helps you can create a new user and copy files from the old user to the new one. This should help for sure.

Comment: but how can I know it's related to dropbox?

Comment: Did you read the error message? :-)

Comment: This package is not installed

Comment: Try to remove dropbox by `sudo apt remove dropbox` then.

Answer (score 1):

You have entered into the World of Hurt (tm) that comes from running GUI programs as `root`. Avoid repeating that mistake.

Details: The "running-as-`root`" GUI programs grab ownership of all sorts of files, then,, when `$USER` tries to access the them, `$USER` cannot, because they're owned by `root`, and `$USER` doesn't have write access to the files, *BOOM*.

Take a look at the last few pages of lines of `strace nautilus` to get a look at what was going on leading up to the `Bus error` message, which probably means out-of-range memory access (or, out-of-permissions).

Check `/var/crash`, one can `less` the crash files.

To find all the files in your `$HOME` directory that you don't own:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls
```

If, after inspection, cogitation, and reinspection, you want to regain ownership:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print0 | xargs -0 -r sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

Comment: chowned all relevant files, still having the error. These are the last lines of the output of `strace nautilus`: https://pastebin.com/jBDURhpm

Comment: Replace `$HOME` with `/run/user/1000/dconf` in my answer. Pesky `root` GUI proggies!

Comment: Sorry... also didn't work. There's was a single file `user` and it was owned by me =/. I added another point to the text about the startup crash.

Answer (score 0):

As this bug is pretty general, I am sharing two things that worked for me when I was in such situation with nautilus. I hope this helps

First thing : **Do not run `sudo nautilus`**

If you did so, you first have to reclaim ownership of all the files in your `$HOME`.
To do so, run the following command in your home directory.

```
sudo chown userhome_directory $USER:$USER
```

You can verify if everything is ok by running `ls -l` you should see that you own the file.

**Now for the two workarounds that worked for me:**

- Sometimes it is just tracker that is buggy, so you can reset it with `sudo tracker reset -r`. The `-r` option is for a hard reset. (You can try a soft reset before with option `-e`)
- The next option is more of a diagnostic (you can jump to the end to see :

1. Try create a new user to check if the problem persists across sessions. If it is then I can't help any further.
2. From the new user open a terminal and run (assuming username)

```
su username
cd $HOME
```

From that remove cache `rm -r .cache` and rename `.profile .config .local` **DO NOT DELETE THEM!**

```
mv .config .config.old
mv .profile .profile.old
mv .local .local.old
```

Now you will log back in your original user (after completing all the initialization steps) and see if you can open nautilus. If the answer is **yes**, then close the session, log back in your temporary user and run:

```
su username
cd $HOME
rm -r .config .local .profile
```

and recover one of the renamed directories (local.old, profile.old, config.old). For example to see if `local.old` is the problem then `mv .local.old local` and relog into your session. If nautilus is still working then try with another directory (profile.old, config.old) and so on. until you found the one that is problematic. Do not forget to remove the generated directories each time.

Once you found the one that is problematic, look inside and try to see what's causing the problem (potentially with the same approach).

**Fastest option to test:**
My problem personnally was due to a corrupted file in `$HOME/.config/nautilus` thus I just ran `mv .config/nautilus .config/nautilus.old` and restart my session
and it worked again.