# Nautilus only starts with sudo, things are missing

Tags: partitioning, gnome, mount, nautilus, fstab

The first thing I realised was that Nautilus wouldn't start anymore. So I started it as root, which made it run.

It produced these errors:

> ** (org.gnome.Nautilus:6189): WARNING **: 09:10:40.711: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei
>   »/root/.gtk-bookmarks«: No such file or directory
>
> ** (org.gnome.Nautilus:6189): WARNING **: 09:10:40.711: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei
>   »/root/.gtk-bookmarks«: No such file or directory
>
> ```
>  (org.gnome.Nautilus:6189): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:10:43.733: gtk_notebook_get_tab_label: assertion 'list != NULL' failed
> ```

Also, it looked different than I'm used to. For example (fitting to the errors) my bookmarks weren't there.

Next I opened Thunar which showed some partitions as not mounted - among others, the "system reserved" (own translation from german, it's sda1) partition. When I mounted "system reserved" all in Thunar, Nautilus was working as normal.

Some duckduckgoing around pointed me in the direction of the file fstab. In fact, it was missing sda1 (system reserved).

Now I will try to append the missing entrys to fstab without breaking something. The Disks app seems to not have an effect.

Does anybody have an idea what may cause fstab to change? I only had stuff like steam and firefox open at the time and the problem appeared on a boot.

Edit: Okay, I am confused. sda1 is the Windows 10 boot partition. I don't know whats wrong.

When I start Nautilus as root, there are "home" and "root directory" as ejectable media in the sidebar.

When I click on "Desktop" in the sidebar, it says "The requested file could not be found."

Help?

Oh, I forgot: I am on 19.10.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! _“The first thing I realised was that Nautilus wouldn't start anymore.”_ Instead of running it as root, you should run it in the terminal and check the errors it throws. _“When I start Nautilus as root, there are "home" and "root directory" as ejectable media in the sidebar.”_ This is probably OK as root can unmount anything… _“When I click on "Desktop" in the sidebar, it says "The requested file could not be found."”_ Does `/root/Desktop` exist? Don’t forget root is a different user from your normal login. See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/754541/250300

Comment: See my answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207412/nautilus-crashes-when-i-open-but-runs-with-sudo/1207428#1207428

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be due to the outdated hard drive my home directory is on. When I give the system some time after booting and don't immediately start a bunch of programs, the problem isn't there. Sorry to have used your time.